# Find the largest number in the database and create new variable

Tags: php

So, i have this table on the database and i have characters like this:

```
A102
A897
B234
B23
C9823
C786
D345 etc...
```

What i need to achieve is:
If the user has enterd A the function should look all the variables that start with A
i.e 
I have :
A102 and A897, i should remove the first character and there remains 102 and 897.
The largest of them is 897, so i should create a new variable A(897+1)=A898 and so on .
The query:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $value[] = $row['id']; // Inside while loop
}
```

I guess it should be something like this:

```
   if ($variable==A) {
    $items = array();
    foreach($value as $value) {
     $items[] = substr('$value', 1);
    max($items); // to find max
    }
   }
```

Approach

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM formas WHERE 'id_f' LIKE '%A%'" ;  
$res = odbc_exec($connection, $result) or die(odbc_error());



    $biggest = 0;
    while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res))
    {
         $current_value = substr($row['id_f'], 1); // return: 102, 897;
         if( $current_value > $biggest )
         {
            $biggest = $current_value; // in the last looping you should get 897.
         }
    }
    echo $result = "A(" . ($biggest + 1) . ")"; // return A(898)
```

Comment: Do you have DB query or that part is problem too?

Comment: Yes, let me write it ...

Comment: If you _ever_ find yourself having to deal with sub-columnar information (like the `897` in `A897`), you're almost certainly doing it wrong - consider a schema change to split the two things into separate columns. It's far more efficient to rejoin than to split.

Comment: Yes, the point is, i need to create id's for A,B,C,D section, i need A1, B1, C1, D1.. I can't do it by autoincrement.. it would mean to have 4 same values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(SELECT MAX(N) as maxid FROM (
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(name, 2) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) as N 
From `mytable` 
) t)

UNION ALL

(SELECT N as maxid FROM (
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(name, 2) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) as N 
From `mytable` 
ORDER BY N DESC) t LIMIT 1)
```

SEE [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a6e/33)

You can simply use one query:

```
SELECT MAX(N) as maxid FROM (
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(name, 2) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) as N 
    From `mytable` 
    ) t
```

Comment: Thanks :)
this too was great one!
so, my issue is, i need to find all name that contain A in it..
and how can i save the value ina  variable..

Comment: just change substr to SUBSTRING in SQL server, also, add WHERE name LIKE 'A%' that's all

Comment: thanks, it now says: The substring function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: Sorry I don't have SQL server, you can see manual for using substring() for SQL server...

Comment: I tried to modify it.. could you please tell me what am i doing wrong here?
SELECT MAX(N) as maxid FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(id_f, 2,len(id_f) -1)  as N 
    From formas  WHERE id_f LIKE '%C'
    ) t

Comment: I get Null, i mean, if i put that condition.. i guess it has to do with the condition!
I need to find all those records which start with the letter A

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about passing parameter. Try this SQL

```
SELECT DER_NAME ||CHAR(COUNTER + 1)
FROM 
(
SELECT SUBSTR(NAME, 1) AS DER_NAME, MAX(INT(SUBSTR(2, NAME))) AS COUNTER
FROM TABLE-NAME
WHERE NAME LIKE 'A%' --SUBSTITUE YOUR PARAMETER
group by SUBSTR(NAME, 1)
) A
```

Comment: This sounds so complicated to me :)

Comment: please, could you help me make it more simple, like, with an example.. so the table name is formas the column name is id_f 
i want to store the largest number which has as a first character A
I use this query with php..

Comment: in the inner query using like operator we are finding maximum number for the records starting with A. In the outer query you again concatenate the letter A and the result of adding 1 to your maximum number from the inner query

Comment: I'm sorry to bother,
but could you show me how to implement this with php, i mean i need to echo the new number you just created...
i need to store it in a value!

Comment: That's okay. But i Don't know php. What I have given here is a query you can use to retrive from data base. Sorry for not being to help

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved by this procedure, correct me if I was wrong. 
(1). You should create a function that take the first character from the user input. Example: `ABC233`, the function should `return "A"` (2)Once you get the character from step 1, you can query it to table. Here is the complete source code:

```
> <?php  
> mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
> mysql_select_db("stackoverflow");
> 
> 
> /* First chars */ 
> function first_char( $str ) 
> {
>     return substr($str, 0, 1); 
> } 
> ?>
> 
> <form action="home.php" method="post"> 
>      Input String : <input type="text" name="txtstring"><br> 
>      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
> 
> <?php 
> if( $_POST['txtstring'] != '' ) 
> {    
>    $char = first_char($_POST['txtstring'] );    
>    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytablWHERE my_field LIKE '%" . $char . "%'") or die(mysql_error());
>  
>    
>     $biggest = 0;
>     while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
>     {
>          $current_value = substr($row['my_field'], 1); // return: 102, 897;
>          if( $current_value > $biggest )
>          {
>             $biggest = $current_value; // in the last looping you should get 897.
>          }
>     }
>     $result = "A(" . ($biggest + 1) . ")"; // return A(898)
>      
>     echo $result;
> 
> } ?>
```

I assume have database named "stackoverflow" and table named "mytable fields: (ID, my_field)"
And the result something like this:

[image]

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi, yes, this logic is correct, but when i echo the result, i just get the value "1"

Comment: I'm sorry: I've changed 
$result = "A(" + $biggest + 1 + ")"; 
to 
$result = "A(" . ($biggest + 1) . ")";
Try it again !

Comment: It's because $biggest = 0. No records found. I've changed again the source code, consider this 'FIELD' LIKE '%A%'". Try it again, and it should be work. :-)

Comment: i'm sorry..it still prints A(1)
EVENTHOUGH I CHANGED IT..LET ME PASTE THE CODE SO YOU CAN LOOK AT IT